# ViewController still stays after unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, dismiss

So I have multiple controllers, lets call them A, B and C.

When I go to A, and select an Item in the tableview, I get transported to B where I can edit the items and save. Now, when I press save, I have an unwind segue which takes me to C, the home page.

However, when I go to A again, the view is still stuck on B and I have to press the tabBarItem again which I used to come to A again, to go back to A. Why does this happen, I just want A to appear again and B to dissapear as soon as I press save.

I have tried code such as:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

in both the segue and the save button code, but nothing seems to happen.

Ok, here is more context as requested:

So this is ViewController A:

[image]

and this is viewController  B:

[image]

so when I press save, it transports me to viewcontroller C: which is this
and this is viewcontrollerC:

[image]

and then, using the tab bar, when I go back to viewcontroller a, I get greeted with this:

[image]

as you can see, the tabbar is on the third option but I am getting greeted with viewcontroller B and then, I have to click on the third option again(the one titled collection) to go back to viewcontroller A.

Hope that makes things clearer, please do let me know if any code is needed.

Comment: More context is needed to answer your question. Is the home page a different view controller? How does it relate to other view controllers? 
What is the meaning of the view A still sticking on B?
Are you presenting view controllers all modally? or pushing each of them into the navigation controller stack?

Comment: Ok I'll add more to the question above

Comment: I've added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you need, try this:

```
class CViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "C"
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Go to A", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToA), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 40)

        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    @objc func goToA() {
        let AVC = AViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(AVC, animated: true)
    }

}


class AViewController : UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "A"
        view.backgroundColor = .green

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let BVC = BViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(BVC, animated: true)
    }



}

class BViewController : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "B"
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("save", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(save), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 40)

        view.addSubview(button)


    }

    @objc func save() {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

If you have some question feel free.
Hope it helps.